# autotools: propagating package version into subpackage

Tags: sh, autotools, autoconf

I have an autotools based package call Foo. For historical reasons (are there ever any other reasons?), this contains a subpackage subBar.

```
Foo -|
     |- configure.ac
     |- Makefile.am
     |- subBar -|
                |- configure.ac
                |- Makefile.am
```

subBar's configure.ac is sufficiently complex for me to wish not messing with it if avoidable. On the other side subBar is so tightly integrated with Foo that it does not make sense to keep a separate version number for it.

Is there a way to propagate Foo's version (from AC_INIT) into subBar? The obvious:

```
subBar/configure.ac:
  AC_INIT([subBar], [$(VERSION)], ...)
```

Does not work due to circular references.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Initializing-configure) provides a possible solution:

> The arguments of AC_INIT must be static, i.e., there should not be any
>   shell computation, quotes, or newlines, but they can be computed by
>   M4... It is permissible to use m4_esyscmd or m4_esyscmd_s for
>   computing a version string that changes with every commit to a version
>   control system (in fact, Autoconf does just that, for all builds of
>   the development tree made between releases).

Since `autoconf` itself uses this in its own `configure.ac`:

```
AC_INIT([GNU Autoconf],
        m4_esyscmd([build-aux/git-version-gen .tarball-version]),
        [bug-autoconf@gnu.org])
```

you need to replace this with a system command or shell script of your own to get a version string. e.g., a top-level file called `.foo-version` with "`MAJOR.MINOR`", and borrowing from `git-version-gen`, something like: `m4_esyscmd([tr -d '\n' < ../.foo-version])`

I suppose you could use the same command in the top-level package, replacing `../` with `./` of course. Since m4 is invoking a system command, you're free to get the version string any way you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I am using git-version-gen to produce the top-level package version. I guess I could also modify it to save a version string to file at the time of autoreconf execution and read it the same string in the subpackages as you suggest. However, I was hoping to find a less obfuscate way of parameter passing ;)

Comment: I would suggest to do the other way around: have Foo use the version number of subBar.  This way you can still `make dist` in subBar and have a self-contained package.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ClusterLabs/libqb/blob/master/build-aux/git-version-gen

This is a shell script file you could adopt...for those not familiar ... then tailor the names to two separate variable files sets   like `.subBar-tarball-version` and `.tarball-version`  and `.subBar-version` and `.version`